# Adding logo in a photo title of a lightbox

Tags: lightbox, photo-gallery, lightbox2

Is it possible to add a logo ie. pic in the footer (photo title/description) of a lightbox.  Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.6.0.2 (http://www.prototypejs.org)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, editing the lightbox.css (i'm writing this answer based on the [Lightox2.0](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) plugin).

```
/* Add this: */
#imageDetails {
    padding: 0 0 0 40px; /* Width of your image */
    background: #FFF url(your-image.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

Another way is by adding a link to the title attribute (Though not the cleanest way):

```
<a href="image.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="<a href='#' class='somelogo'>Link</a>Some text to display"><img src="thumb.jpg" width="100" height="40" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: that is sort of a solution, but there is an issue if one would use different logo on different photo, or different set of photos on one page. What about adding a link instead of a logo? Is that possible without interfering with html code of a parent page?

Comment: I Have added a link within the title attribute. Maybe with a class you can add the logo to the link.

Comment: How did you add a link within the title. Could you paste the code?

Comment: Yes I have the same thing, but doesn't it look ugly when all this code pops up when hoovering over thumbnail?

Comment: Yes, it does. The other way around that is to change the plugin code to add a class or something to the divs, I'm sure it's not too hard.